# Python: "str" object is not callable

Tags: python, sqlite

This code is for a project I'm working on; I'm apparently trying to call a string. The program is designed to print quiz scores from an SQLite database; method 1, which is what I'm having problems with, should give the most recent records of all students of the right class and difficulty level. The database looks like this;

`CREATE TABLE Scores ( 
    [Key]       INTEGER,
    Score       INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    PupilName   TEXT     NOT NULL,
    Difficulty  BOOLEAN  NOT NULL,
    ClassNumber VARCHAR,
    DateTime    DATETIME 
);`

and the code (with the odd bit of debug) like this:

```js
import sqlite3

#import collections
print ("Welcome to the Arithmetic Challenge high score table.")
def MainLoop():
    DisplayType = input ("Please enter: 1 for highest scores by student in alphabetical order; 2 for highest scores, highest to lowest; 3 for average scores, highest to lowest. ")
    Difficulty = input ("Enter difficulty level.")
    ClassNumber = input ("Enter class number.") #Input of variables
    conn = sqlite3.connect("QuizStorage")
    c = conn.cursor()#Connects
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM Scores")                            
    PupilsEligible = c.fetchall()#Finds pupils
    #count = collections.defaultdict(int) #?
    #print (count)
    print (PupilsEligible)
    DifficultyInt = int(Difficulty)
    if DisplayType == "1":
        print (DifficultyInt)
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM Scores WHERE Difficulty = (?) AND ClassNumber = (?) ORDER BY # DESC LIMIT 1 ORDER BY PupilName"(DifficultyInt, ClassNumber))
        data = c.fetchall()
        print (data)
    elif DisplayType == "2":
        c.execute("SELECT * , MAX(Score) FROM Scores WHERE Difficulty = (?) AND ClassNumber = (?) GROUP BY PupilName"(DifficultyInt, ClassNumber))
        data = c.fetchall()
        print (data)
    elif DisplayType == "3":
        c.execute("SELECT * , AVG(Score) FROM Scores WHERE Difficulty = (?) AND ClassNumber = (?) GROUP BY PupilName"(DifficultyInt, ClassNumber))
        data = c.fetchall()
        print (data)

    else:
        print ("That's not a valid answer.")
    for row in c:
        print (row)
    conn.close()
    MainLoop()
MainLoop()
```

Please note that this code has various relics of earlier attempts that haven't yet been pruned off. Sorry if this makes it unclear.
When I try to run it, I get this :

```html
Welcome to the Arithmetic Challenge high score table.
Please enter: 1 for highest scores by student in alphabetical order; 2 for highest scores, highest to lowest; 3 for average scores, highest to lowest. 1
Enter difficulty level.2
Enter class number.3
[('Alice Mann',), ('Fred Pratt',), ('John Smith',), ('Karen James',)]
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\My Documents\CA 2\ACHighScore 0.5.5.py", line 37, in <module>
    MainLoop()
  File "H:\My Documents\CA 2\ACHighScore 0.5.5.py", line 19, in MainLoop
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM Scores WHERE Difficulty = (?) AND ClassNumber = (?) ORDER BY # DESC LIMIT 1 ORDER BY PupilName"(DifficultyInt, ClassNumber))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I've looked at the other similar errors and been left none the wiser. What exactly does this error message mean, and how can it be avoided?

Comment: You have `c.execute("some string"(data))`. Python thinks you're trying to call a string as a function.

Comment: ...where it should be `c.execute("some string where blah=(?) and foo=(?) ", (x1, x2))` to put the values in the question mark places. You missed a comma.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the following line (like the error message says): `c.execute("SELECT * ...`
It's because when you do

```
"it's a string"(arg1, arg2))
           ^^^^^^^
```

you are trying do *call* a string. You've probably missed a comma there: `"it's a string", (arg1, arg2)`
Note that you have multiple similar errors in your code